# Missing Return Statement in Nested Switch Statements

Tags: java, switch-statement, return, case

I'm writing a section of code for a Rock, Paper, Scissors game. I am writing a method that returns 1, 0 or -1 depending on wether the computer wins, it's a tie, or the user wins, respectively. I have this code so far:

```
private int nextPlay(char computerMove, char playerMove) {
    switch (playerMove) {
        case 'R': switch (computerMove) {
            case 'R': return 0;
            case 'P': return 1;
            case 'S': return -1;
        }
        case 'P': switch (computerMove) {
            case 'R': return -1;
            case 'P': return 0;
            case 'S': return 1;
        }
        case 'S': switch (computerMove) {
            case 'R': return 1;
            case 'P': return -1;
            case 'S': return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

It throws a "Missing Return Statement" at me at the last bracket. Any suggestions?

P.S. the only options available for both computerMove and playerMove are R, P and S!

Comment: add in a default case and perform some error handling

Comment: What happens if `playerMove` is not `'R'`, `'P'`, or `'S'`? Remember, as far as compiler knows, it can have any character value. Add `throw new IllegalStateException("Oops! I messed up!!")` at the end of the method.

Comment: The compiler doesn't know that the only available options are `R`, `P`, and `S`.  From its point of view, they could be any other character.

Comment: Alright thanks everyone, I tried all of the suggestions, nothing seems to fix the cluster of errors that pops out if I try any of the fixes and I think it's an error with the entire program, not the section I'm working on. Thanks everyone!

Comment: i suggest you just use an if-else structure with nested if

Answer (score 1):

Others are telling you to add `default` to your `switch` statements. Not needed at all in this case, though it's a good general rule to follow.

However, you need to consider what should happen if `playerMove` and/or `computerMove` doesn't have one of the 3 expected values (`'R'`, `'P'`, or `'S'`).

If `computerMove` doesn't, you'd want the logic flow to exit the outer `switch` statement, rather than fall through to the next `case` (though technically they'd all just fall through then, but still), so add a `break` in each outer `case`.

If that breaks out, or if `playerMove` doesn't have valid value, then logic flow gets to end of method, and there is no `return` statement there. *That* is your compilation error.

Best solution here, since you hopefully can't get into that situation, is to declare that to be **exceptional**, i.e. `throw` an `Exception`.

You code could be:

```
private int nextPlay(char computerMove, char playerMove) {
    switch (playerMove) {
        case 'R':
            switch (computerMove) {
                case 'R': return 0;
                case 'P': return 1;
                case 'S': return -1;
            }
            break;
        case 'P':
            switch (computerMove) {
                case 'R': return -1;
                case 'P': return 0;
                case 'S': return 1;
            }
            break;
        case 'S':
            switch (computerMove) {
                case 'R': return 1;
                case 'P': return -1;
                case 'S': return 0;
            }
            break;
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException("Oops! I messed up!!");
}
```

But it's better with more descriptive error messages:

```
private int nextPlay(char computerMove, char playerMove) {
    switch (playerMove) {
        case 'R':
            switch (computerMove) {
                case 'R': return 0;
                case 'P': return 1;
                case 'S': return -1;
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid computer move: " + computerMove);
        case 'P':
            switch (computerMove) {
                case 'R': return -1;
                case 'P': return 0;
                case 'S': return 1;
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid computer move: " + computerMove);
        case 'S':
            switch (computerMove) {
                case 'R': return 1;
                case 'P': return -1;
                case 'S': return 0;
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid computer move: " + computerMove);
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid player move: " + playerMove);
}
```

Now, you could add those `throw` statements in a `default` clause instead. Same result.

```
private int nextPlay(char computerMove, char playerMove) {
    switch (playerMove) {
        case 'R':
            switch (computerMove) {
                case 'R': return 0;
                case 'P': return 1;
                case 'S': return -1;
                default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid computer move: " + computerMove);
            }
        case 'P':
            switch (computerMove) {
                case 'R': return -1;
                case 'P': return 0;
                case 'S': return 1;
                default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid computer move: " + computerMove);
            }
        case 'S':
            switch (computerMove) {
                case 'R': return 1;
                case 'P': return -1;
                case 'S': return 0;
                default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid computer move: " + computerMove);
            }
        default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid player move: " + playerMove);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion

```
public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

            int x=nextPlay('R','P');
            System.out.println(x);
        }
        private static int nextPlay(char computerMove, char playerMove) 
        {
            if(playerMove=='R')
            {
                if(computerMove=='R')
                    return 0;
                else if(computerMove=='P')
                    return 1;
                else
                    return -1;
            }
            else if(playerMove=='P')
            {
                if(computerMove=='R')
                    return -1;
                else if(computerMove=='P')
                    return 0;
                else
                    return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                if(computerMove=='R')
                    return 1;
                else if(computerMove=='P')
                    return -1;
                else
                    return 0;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much everyone! I decided to simply set one of the cases in each switch statement to default (keeping track of which char it is of course) and it resolved the issue.

I know this can cause some issues if the char is anything but the intended one, but my teacher says it is ok and I would use a different method (as suggested) next time!